# How to rewrite URL after redirect to another url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem to redirect page in paging system. I have write .htaccess as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^news.html?page=2 allnews.php?type=1&page2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news.html allnews.php?type=1 [NC]
```

Actually I want to add paging system in the news.html. But it is not working :(

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry for mistake typing first line is RewriteRule ^news.html?page=2 allnews.php?type=1&page=2 [NC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably final URI should be `allnews.php?type=1&page=2` instead of `allnews.php?type=1&page2`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news\.html$ /allnews.php?type=1 [NC,QSA]
```